# Calculate $\int^3_0 \frac{\ln2}{2} \left(2^{x-3}-2^{3-x}\right)$

Tags: definite-integrals, logarithms, exponential-function, area

$$\begin{align}
Definite\,integral & = \int^3_0 \frac{\ln2}{2} \left(2^{x-3}-2^{3-x}\right)\\
 & =  \frac12\int^3_0 \ln 2 \left(2^{x-3}-2^{3-x}\right)\\ 
 & =  \frac12\int^3_0 \ln 2 \cdot 2^{x-3}-\ln2\cdot2^{3-x}\\
 & =  \frac12\left[2^{x-3}-2^{3-x}\right]^3_0\\ 
 & = 0.5\left(0-\left(-\frac{63}{8}\right)\right) = 3\frac{15}{16}
\end{align}$$

However, according to my book and [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0.5+integrate+ln2+2%5E(x-3)+-+ln+2+2%5E(3-x)+dx+from+x%3D0+to+3), this should be $-3 \frac{1}{16}$.

Does someone spot my mistake? Thanks!

Comment: Hint: Chain rule says $\frac d{dx}2^{3-x}=\color{red}{-}\ln2\cdot2^{3-x}$.

Comment: Fourth equality is wrong. Primitive function to $-\ln(2) \cdot 2^{3-x}$ is $2^{3-x}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\int \ln2 \cdot 2^{3-x}=\color{red}-2^{3-x} $$

Therefore :  $$\int^3_0 \frac{\ln2}{2} \left(2^{x-3}-2^{3-x}\right)$$ \begin{align}
 &=  \frac12\int^3_0 \ln 2 \cdot 2^{x-3}-\ln2\cdot2^{3-x}\\
 & = \frac12\left[2^{x-3}\color{red}+2^{3-x}\right]^3_0\\ 
 & = \frac12\left(2-\left(\frac{65}{8}\right)\right) = -3\frac{1}{16}
\end{align}

as provided the answer in your textbook.

Comment: Aaah the minus sign!